# AJAX response not valid in C++ but Apache

Tags: c++, ajax, sockets, request, response

I want to make a server written in C++ to power my game. I learned the basics of sockets and wrote a basic chat program that worked well. Now I want to create an HTTP server like Apache, but only for the AJAX request-response part.

I think just for the beginning i copied one Apache response text, and i sent the exact response with the C++ server program.

The problem that is that the browser (Firefox) connnects to the apache and everything works fine, except all of the requests get a correct response.

But if i send this with the C++ client, then FireBug tells me that the response status is OK (200) but there is no actual response text. (How is this possible?)

This response-text is exactly the same what apache sends. I made a bit-bit comparison and they were the same.

The php file wich is the original response

```
<?php echo "AS";echo  rand(0,9); ?>
```

And the origional source code:

- Socket.h http://pastebin.com/bW9qxtrR
- Socket.cpp http://pastebin.com/S3c8RFM7
- main.cpp http://pastebin.com/ckExuXsR
- index.html http://pastebin.com/mcfEEqPP < this is the requester file.
- ajax.js http://pastebin.com/uXJe9hVC
- benchmark.js http://pastebin.com/djSYtKg9

jQuery is not needed.

*The main.cpp there is lot of trash code like main3 and main4 functions, these do not affect the result.*

I know that the response stuff in the C++ code is not really good because the connection closing is not the best; I will fix that later now I want to send a success response first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem:
the index.html is served through apache on port 80. the browser loads it and starting sending requests.
The request file (program) was on another port , on the 8888 port, which already is a **different server** which dont enables ajax (dont know why) to get the post data. the program can still communicate with *remote* servers but cant see the response.

after one whole day i tested a lot with the fiddler program , captured the responses, and that method helped me.

I used the fiddler program to capture the the good answer and to capture the bad. They were the same. After this i turned off my socket application, and forced fiddler to auto respond, and the answer from the 'bad' answer still bat. So after that i replaced the bad with the good and nothing happedned. The bad answer with the good text still bad on the :8888 port but the other on the original :80 port was good, but they were absolutly the same and the same program sended it (fiddler) i think there is something missing if the response is not on the same server address (even not the same port).

after this i thought maybe there is a missing header file, or something ike this.
So i configurated apache to listen on the 80 port, loaded in the index.html. after this i shut down the apache server and changed the port to 8888 and i run the ajax requests and i recognized that they are wrong, but they were sent by the apache, and all of the previorus requests (on the same port) were good. so the problem is only with the ajax stuff :D

many thanks to Tony Lee for the **Fiddler** suggestion.

Actually there is no solution but there is an answer why the problem exists.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. XmlHttpRequest only accepts connections to the same host than the html file. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're verifying bit-by-bit - if you used [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to capture the traffic then this is a mystery.

I'm going to guess the unsent buffered data is lost when you close the socket.  See the MSDN article [Graceful Shutdown, Linger Options, and Socket Closure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Call [shutdown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before you call closesocket() to ensure a clean shutdown.

Comment: aboute the shutdown stuff, i dont really shut the socket down because the ajax transmission main benefit that the socket is not closed during the process.

Comment: funny, i tried to use this fiddler, this is very good, but my program broke down after the first request if i use this, not when  only run without the fiddler :S

Comment: thanks for your tip, finally i found out what the problem is :D

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but you might find it useful.

Instead of Apache code you can try [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/). It has functions just to make http servers and it probably will be much faster than Apache code.

Check [this link](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/12/how-to-build-a-custom-static-file-serving-http-server-using-libevent-in-c/). There is some info about building http server with libevent.