# JSON in ajax with mongoose

Tags: ajax, json, sockets, mongoose-web-server

I have the following Mongoose server (the [server](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/), not the javascript library):

```
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "{ \"key\" : \"value\"}";

        mg_printf(conn,
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            "Cache: no-cache\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
            "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
            "\r\n",
            oss.str().length());
        mg_write(conn, oss.str().c_str(), oss.str().length());
```

When I open the page in Firefox, it works well, I can see the JSON message `{ "key" : "value"}`. Firebug is happy with it, and shows me the interpreted JSON object.

When I access the same URL with `$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/AtoB", [...] )`, Firebug shows me the correct header, but an empty body.

What should I do ? 
Thanks

Additional info :

- Doesn't work with application/json either. I left text/plain for ease of debugging.
- Doesn't work with $.get() or others. The problem is before.
- Doesn't work with a raw xmlhttprequest, too !
- I tried with a final \0 and a final \n with no luck.
- The original mongoose server (mongoose.exe) produces the same behaviour when accessed from jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So XmlHttpRequest only accepts connections to the same host... I knew that, but competely forgot.

The .html file must be accessed through Mongoose too (same host, same port) instead of using file://

This question really was a duplicate of [AJAX response not valid in C++ but Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861935/ajax-response-not-valid-in-c-but-apache)